# Search exactly value of field in solr

Tags: search, solr, exact-match

I have table "class". This class has a field: "numStudents". I indexed numStudents field.

Now I want to search all classes have numStudents = 10, for example. How can I do this?

Please give me easiest way, modify solrconfig.xml or schema.xml is good for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to filter out all the classes which has 10 students without actually scoring the documents.
You can use the Filter Query fq=numStudents:10 to filter out the classes.
[FilterQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) is able to take advantage of the [FilterCache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache), which would be a huge performance boost in comparison to your queries.